# Virtual host based on Context Path

Tags: apache

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName host.company.com
    JkMount  /a/* worker_1
    JkMount  /b/* worker_2
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual Host based on the server context path.

Is it possible to have differentiate virtual host if url starts with /r

Comment: VirtualHost can be desinguished by (one or more of): 1) IP address, 2) Host: header and 3) port number. But if you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve, there is probably a solution.

Comment: @DusanBajic. Thank you. I was trying to identify the request starting with /r. Then perform basicAuth and reverse proxy those requests to some other server by stripping /r. Can you throw some light on it how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName localhost

    <Location /a/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Path A"
    Require valid-user
    AuthUserFile passwords/a.htpasswd

    ProxyPass "http://localhost:8000/"

    </Location>

    <Location /b/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Path b"
    Require valid-user
    AuthUserFile passwords/b.htpasswd

    ProxyPass "http://localhost:8001/"

    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will tryout this and get back soon

Comment: As your in example, for location /a if I do not need basic auth, can we skip putting inside Location

Comment: If no Auth is needed, remove the 4 auth related lines. Location is still needed as a criteria to which backend the request should be proxied. If you really want to remove <Location>, then the rule should be something like `ProxyPass "/a/" "http://localhost:8000/"`

Comment: The Proxy Pass is not appending the request. http://localhost:80/b/abc/cdf-> http://localhost:8001/abc/cdf. But it is just going to http://localhost:8001. Can you help

Comment: (also see edit, it might be important, depending on the backend service)

Comment: Yes. I made it work now. One more thing, is there any way I can log these proxy requests like input url and proxied  url.

Comment: Requests are logged in access_log by default. If you add `LogLevel proxy:debug` to Virtual Host conf, additonal proxy info will be logged to error_log. You might need to play around with verbosity level. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#loglevel